# How do I export and use a function defined with this type of component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-table

So, I have a file called `UserPaginatedDataTable.js` which looks like this:
https://pastecord.com/icagatowul.js

It contains a function called `searchHandler` here:

```js
 const searchHandler = () => {
        setClearFilters(false);
        memoDataHandler();
    };
```

I'd like to import that function (and whatever dependencies it requires) over to a different file called `TableFilters.js`.

```js
import UserPaginatedDataTable from "../UserPaginatedDataTable";
.
.
.
export const InputColumnFilter = ({ column }) => {
    const { filterValue, setFilter } = column;
    return (
        <span>
            <input value={filterValue || ""} onChange={(e) => {
                setFilter(e.target.value);
                if (e.charCode === 13) {
                    searchHandler() // where I plan to call the function
                }
            } } className="table-col-filter"
                 />
        </span>
    );
};
```

However, I'm getting a `'searchHandler' is not defined.` and `'UserPaginatedDataTable' is defined but never used.` message. Even only trying to import `searchHandler` by itself results in a parsing error because of an unexpected token: https://pastecord.com/madubilova.js (`TableFilters.js`)

Am I doing imports for this kind of component wrong?

Comment: `searchHandler` is essentially a private function to that component. Is `InputColumnFilter` contained within `PaginatedDataTable`? If so, you could pass `searchHandler` as a prop to it. It depends on your setup but you may better served utilizing a context provider.

Comment: `InputColumnFilter` is not contained with `PaginatedDataTable` but I could try that. How would I pass it as a prop though? This is what it looks like atm: https://pastecord.com/imuroconut.js

Comment: You would just allow for that new function prop to exist in the components just like you would any other. `<PaginatedDataTable searchHandler={searchHandler} ...` then you would do the same with `InputColumnFilter`. If you don't or can't move the component inside, you could move the hooks to a higher component and pass them down through those props instead.